# The unusable state of S-R Latch simulation in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, cmos, vlsi

I created an S-R Latch in spice using MOS transistors (180nm) and gave noth S and R inputs as 1 (knowing that this state is unusable as both Q and Qbar will be metastable). But I was expecting identical values for Q and Qbar since the circuit is symetrical, but got different values as shown, with a difference of about 0.3V . I tried it out of curiosity, but am unable to think of possible explaination for this.

Operating conditions: VDD=3.3V, S=R=3.3V
Q = 864mV
Qbar = 548mV

[image]

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, can you export the schematic as a graphic file from LTspice? The details of your circuit are pretty much unreadable, and the waveform plot doesn't add any information. Can you provide the dc operating point values?

Comment: By the way, setting S=R=1 **does not** make the outputs become metastable.

Comment: I should do so I think, as the pull down circuitry is discharging output nodes and at the same time turning on the pull up circuit, that again charges the outputs. Let me know if I missed anything

Comment: If you have both a pulldown and a pullup acting on the same node then you do not have a valid CMOS circuit. The result of this is not metastability, it is **contention**.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In meta stable condition, output lies somewhere between 0 and 1 for indefinite amount of time and so is the case here, So how are both of these things different ?

Comment: Metastable conditions will eventually resolve to valid logic levels even if the inputs do not change but contention will have an invalid voltage (logic level) as long as the inputs have the invalid value.

Comment: Also, a metastable condition requires **feedback** but contention can occur in a purely combinational circuit.

Comment: So in this case of contention, the Q and QBar values should have been identical though. Please explain the above query and let me know if anything is needed from my side. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: If your circuit isn't proper CMOS then I'm not going to try to analyze it. However, there is no requirement that two nodes in contention have the same voltage.

Comment: @SparshSharma Modify your shortcut for LTspice to have the `-FixUpSchematicFonts` switch, it will make the labels larger (the same size as the rest, `1.5`). Otherwise it's not possible to read the labels and the reference designators.

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to connect all your NMOS body terminals to VSS?

Comment: I considered shorting source and body terminals to avoid body effect

Comment: @SparshSharma  Ok, but just keep in mind that's not really done in typical CMOS process.  Your threshold voltage is gonna be a bit different for the top transistors.

Answer (score 1):

The schematic is not symmetrical, M6 and M8 (if I reversed didn't get those numbers right they are very hard to see) are upside down from the MOSFETs across from them.

Check the model to see if it's symmetrical (I don't know which model you're using I can't see it on the schematic to check it myself) It probably is not.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean ? I am new to spice. I have a tsmc180nm library for nmos and pmos and all these transistors are identical .

Comment: Look at the subckt for the library and double check the symmetry, I doubt the transistors are symmetrical physically, if so you have the terminals reversed in your circuit above.

Comment: http://ptm.asu.edu/modelcard/180nm_bulk.txt

Comment: It doesn't matter if the device dimensions of nmos and pmos are different, as all nmos have identical dimensions, and so do the pmos. I am talking about circuit symmetry here , i.e both Q and Qbar should be having some intermediate value .

Comment: You can find out if you reverse the terminals of M6 and M8

Comment: Wht do you actually mean by inverting the terminals

Comment: M8 and M6 are upside down, look at the gates